# How can I give Python's "keyboard" and "mouse" modules root permissions to run?

Tags: 20.04, root, python3

I made a simple Python script using it's keyboard and mouse modules for the purpose of saving me a few minutes of clicking and typing. Once I had done a bit of debugging, I ran the script. The disappointing part was that when run, the terminal returned: `Root privileges are required to use this module.` I tried running the same script using `chmod` in a root terminal, but that didn't work either. I am the root user, which confuses me even more. I already posted this question on Stackoverflow with no luck. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this when reading about keyboard and mouse modules. I noticed there are no replies yet and it's been a couple of months. If you still have the same issue the command you are looking for is:

```
sudo python3 /path/to/file.py
```

From [`man sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

> ```
> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser
> or another user, as specified by the security policy.
> ```